# T4 tool for XCode

Tags: xcode, code-generation, t4, texttemplate

Does anything like the T4 text template generation tool of visual studio exist for XCode?

Thanks for help,
Enyra

Comment: Does xCode have an extensibility model? If so, you could perhaps use the Mono implementation of T4 with a suitable binding shim to hook it to the (presumably) native code of xCode's extensibility.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using XSLT template generation to create objective c files. T4 just allows you to write code in your templates which is not necessary, instead just create an XMl model and use XSLT to transform it into code.

Maybe use a tool like this one? http://ditchnet.org/xslpalette/